# Creating a list of reference links, added by users

Tags: views, uri

How would I create a  list of links that would reference internal and external links. The links would be apart of a node(a page)

Here's what I want. A user would have a way to "ADD a link" to the list. The list would be a node like a page. Once this link is added to the page, it will show a link not URL and would be Alphabetically indexed. The list would be in a table and have a pager to prevent overflow.

My thinking is that what I want is a module to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like what I am trying to do, but does not allow users to add the links to the list(page) . https://drupal.org/node/110818

Comment: Try looking at the [Link](https://drupal.org/project/link) and [EVA](https://drupal.org/project/Eva) modules. EVA will allow you to display a link attached to the node, so you can display the fields in a table.